# How can I display tags in archive.php as a drop down menu in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tags

how can I display tags in archive.php (for each post) as a drop down menu in Wordpress?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WordPress plugin 'Taxonomy Dropdown Widget' and add a widget in your right or left sidebar to display the dropdown of tags on an archive page. Just make sure you have sidebar added on archive page and follow steps as in below screenshots:

Taxonomy Dropdown Widget:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tag-dropdown-widget/

[image]

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: Thanks for reply but I need to show tags for each post in archive pages (categories and tag pages), not in sidebar.